# Need help in Web Application Setup on Windows Server 2012 R2/IIS 8.5

Tags: iis-8.5

We are migrating to the Windows Server 2012 R2 and we need to deploy all our Web application built using .Net 4.0 to the same server. Earlier the applications were running on Windows Server 2003 R2.

I have deployed the application and create a Virtual Directory under the Default Website in IIS.
When I try accessing the application from IE or browsing the application from IIS, it shows the directory listing and when I click any link it gives me the below error:
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Can anyone please suggest if anything is wrong with the application setup. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Neeraj